# Search and replace with find and xargs not working

Tags: find, xargs

I am trying to search and replace a url present in source code of html/css files in target folder and subfolders. I have tried to use the following command :

```
find . -type f | xargs sed -i  's/https\:*\.websitedomain\.fr\///g'
```

What i am i missing ?

Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: What files do you have? Show example input file contents, actual result and expected result.

Comment: I'm not sure what your trying to do, but itloks like your sed command is wrong. What are you truing to accomplish?

Comment: If `*` in your pattern is meant as "any number of characters" like in file globbing, then you have to use `.*` instead. To avoid matching `\.websitedomain\.fr\/` in the file or argument part of an URL I suggest to use `[^/]*` (any number of any characters but `/`) instead.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a GNU system (which your usage of `sed -i` suggests is the case for you):

```
eregex='https://[^/[:space:]]+\.websitedomain\.fr/'
find . -type f -exec grep -lZEe "$eregex" {} + |
  xargs -r0 sed -i -E "s|$eregex||g"
```

Some of the problems in your approach:

- the main one is that the `*` regexp operator matches 0 or more of the previous atom, so `:*` matches 0 or more `:`s. Here we're replacing it with `[^/[:space:]]+` which is 1 or more (`+`, an extended regex operator, hence the `-E`s) characters other than whitespace and `/` (`.*` which is probably what you had in mind could end up matching `google.com/ and foo` in `https://google.com/ and foo.websitedomain.fr/file` for instance).
- The output format of `find -print` (one file path per line) is not compatible with the expected input format of `xargs` (expects blank or newline separated, possibly quoted words). The output format of `find -print` is not post-processable reliably, it should only be used for human consumption. Better to use `find ... -exec cmd {} +`, and/or use NUL-delimited records with `xargs -r0` (`-r` and `-0` being GNU extensions).
- `sed -i` replaces the files with a modified copy of the original, with possible loss of metadata information, so it's best to avoid running on files that are not going to be modified, hence the use or `grep -lZ` to get a list (NUL delimited with `-Z` so it can be used by `xargs -0`) of files with at least one line matching the regex.
- `:` is not a regexp operator so doesn't need to be escaped. What `\:` matches is unspecified by POSIX and undocumented in most `sed` implementations. So while currently it may match on a `:` in your `sed` implementation, that may change in the future (like `\<` or `\w` while originally matching on `<` and `w` respectively ended up matching a word boundary and word character in newer versions).
- if your regexp or replacement in `sed`'s `s` command contains a `/`, it's easier to use a different character as the delimiter than having to escape `/` with backslashes which makes it quite hard to read. Hence `s|regexp|replacement|g` here instead of `s/regexp/replacement/g`. I do like `|` as it makes for legible code. It has the disadvantage that it can't be used in `ex`/`vi`'s `s/regex/replacement/` though as `|` separates `ex` commands there (it's also an extended regex operator).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```bsh
find . -type f | xargs sed -i  's/test\.com/set\.com/g'
```

If you need to test for the inclusion of *https* then try this:

```bsh
find . -type f | xargs sed -i  's/https\:\\\\test\.com/https\:\\\\set\.com/g'
```

> NOTE*: this replaces ***test.com*** with ***set.com***